# Error with the type of my props when i import, Ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can someone help me? I am using TypeScript, StyledComponent and React with Create React App. This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

```sh
// browser and terminal error

TypeScript error in ./src/index.tsx(4,1):
Type '{ alt: string; src: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'alt' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.  TS2322
```

```sh
// ./src/components/Image/index.tsx

import React from 'react'
import Styled from 'styled-components/macro'

interface ImageInterface {
  alt?: string | undefined
  src: string
}

const Image = Styled.img`
  max-width: 100%;
`

export default () => ({ alt, src }: ImageInterface) => (
  <Image alt={alt || 'My alternative text'} src={src} />
)
```

```sh
// ./src/index.tsx

import React from 'react'
import Image from './components/Image'

<Image src="https://cjpatoilo.com/initify/artwork.png" />
```

```sh
// ./package.json

  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.19",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
  },
```

I hope the normal Image compile component without error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely in your `./src/components/Image/index.tsx` file. The default export is a function that returns a component. But it's being used in `./src/index.tsx` as if it's a function component.

The first option is to remove this wrapping function:

```
// ./src/components/Image/index.tsx

export default ({ alt, src }: ImageInterface) => (
  <Image alt={alt || 'My alternative text'} src={src} />
)
```

Or, invoke this method and then use the return value as the component.

```js
// ./src/index.tsx

import Fn from './components/Image'

const Image = Fn();

<Image src="https://cjpatoilo.com/initify/artwork.png" />
```

Comment: and how would you do it excluding the function?

Comment: Please see the first option, the one I shared for ` ./src/components/Image/index.tsx`. That code was changed from the code you provided.